# Angular JS template now showing

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

I am having issues trying to show a partial html on my index.html file (Nothing is displayed).

Please see my index.html code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My AngularJS App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/animations.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <li>
            <a href="#people">Show People</a>
        </li>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I try to load people.html that is on partials directory, using routing on app.js:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'filters', 'services', 'directives', 'controllers']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/people', {
        templateUrl : 'patials/people.html',
        controller : 'PeopleController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/people'
    });
}]);
```

If I replace the ng-view part on my index.html with my template file content, everything displays fine, so I dont think I have an issue on my controller declarations.

Can you take a look and help me figuring out what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure its not a typo here -- the path says 'patials/people.html' (not partials).. Can you post a jsfiddle in case its still a problem

Comment: I fixed that line but it is still bot loading.

Comment: Plnkr.co will probably work better here since the issue has to do with route and multiple files.  Also check your console and network tab and scripts tab in the chrome debugger (or whatever debugger) and see if there are A any errors in the console, B any failed requests in the network tab and C it's loading your scripts and hits breakpoints in your code.

Comment: Try to set templateUrl to '/partials/people.html'. And check network tab of your browser devtool to verify that your template is requested from http://app.com/partials/people.html, not http://app.com**/people**/partials/people.html

Comment: Thanks to all. I checked javascript console and logs and the only issue I have there is about 2 css files not being found (I fixed that now). My code is on pinkr.com on this link http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6CZJ91KzmHw9FWhhKNP?p=catalogue I was not able to create directories so please ignore paths for js includes

Comment: don't do this in the controller `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);` If you add `,[]` after the module name, angular will create a new module... so in the controller, use just `var myApp = angular.module('myApp');`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bK9vHSPxKmijhlLPS5C5?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You are using `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);` inside your controller. If you add an array as a second parameter in `angular.module`, the module is automatically created as a new one and overrides the previous one with the same name, so the `config` is not working anymore, because in your code it is defined on a different module.

Just change the code in the `PeopleController` definition from

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

to

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
```

and it should work

edited plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bK9vHSPxKmijhlLPS5C5?p=preview

Comment: That solved my problem, but I also needed to change another line, on app.js: var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'filters', 'services', 'directives', 'controllers']); for this = var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

Comment: Thanks! I still dont understand what was wrong with that line on app.js

Comment: It was also corrected in my plunk, but I thought it was intentional. The reason was those strings in the array are names of modules which `myApp` depend on... and apparently those modules didn't exist in your app, so it threw instantiation errors.